# Cannot swap out dlls. Cannot find the implementation when it does exist

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll, version

I have a dll that needs a slight change.  I build the dll, then go to copy over the old one, and I get the following error:

```
Method 'GetUsefulGroupCombinations' in type 'GroupAdmin' from assembly 'Service, Version=1.0.5423.14822, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.
System.TypeLoadException: Method 'GetUsefulGroupCombinations' in type 'GroupAdmin' from assembly 'Service, Version=1.0.5423.14822, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' does not have an implementation.
   at System.Reflection.Assembly._GetType(String name, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)
   at System.Reflection.Assembly.CreateInstance(String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
   at Services.Controller.LoadObject(String name)
   at Services.Controller.GetObject(String name)
   at Util.ServiceFactory.get_GroupAdmin()
   at Services.DataSources2.DataSourcePoller.SynchronizeRules(IDBConnection db, UInt32 lastSyncTime, UInt32 utcUpdateTime)
   at Services.DataSources2.DataSourcePoller.ThreadProc()
```

Now, its important to note that the new dll i put DOES have the exact same implementation as the old dll which works fine.

The first thing I did was change the version of the new dll to match the version of the old dll.  When I view the new dll, i see the new version, but the stack trace still shows the new dlls OLD version before i changed it.  Any idea how/why the stack trace is still picking up the new dlls old version?  I think that is what is causing my problems.

Thanks!

Comment: In the output window of VS (where debug output is shown) you can see the location from where the DLL is loaded. Does it load from the path that you expect?

Comment: Yes, it is loading the correct dll from the correct location.

Comment: Is there maybe still a pdb file in place which messes up your exception message?

Comment: There are zero pdbs in place.

Comment: Are you loading the Assembly dynamically (by calling Assembly.LoadFile or something) or do you have a reference added to it in the references list? If you have a reference, can you delete it and add it again to the References?

Comment: I have the reference added to the list in VS.  However, in this case, I cannot build the solutions again.  I can only build the new DLL by itself and copy it over the old DLL.

Comment: In that case, could be a lot of things. Framework version? characters upper/lowercase in GetUsefulGroupCombinations? x86/x64 setting...